# TwoWay mode binding scenario for null or empty data passed back to source

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding

I have two WPF windows:
- one displays a list of data 
- the other shows a detailed view of a particular data when the button in list is clicked

[image]

[image]

THE ACTUAL PROBLEM : 
When i remove or delete the Car Type data from textbox or basically string values - the "empty" value is reflected back to list of data.
The textboxes are using Twoway mode.
However if i delete or empty the textbox that contains enum data or int data the empty value is not reflected back to list, only problem arises when the data is in string.

Below is snapshot of data that is selected from ListView:

[image]

New to MVVM architecture and WPF please take it easy on me :|

Comment: The behavior of the `string` type seems fine to me.  Two way binding means that the value in the `textbox` reflects the value in your `model` and vice versa.  As for `int` and `enum` values, they are value types and have a default value of 0 which is probably why you don't see a change reflected.

Comment: please show us some code. for example your enum !

Comment: @FelixD. i dont think posting enum code will make a difference its in my Data Layer and has nothing to do with my MVVM UI space

Comment: as far as I have understood your question the problem is your binding to an `enum` so that `Binding` in xaml and that enum are relevant to solve your problem. You should add **everything** relevant.

Comment: @StephenWilson so how do i stop string from forwarding empty data - " " back to my main list ?

Comment: @FelixD. No my binding is a Car object that contains an enum property as well as int,string

Comment: and thats exaclty why u should add code. it cant be missunderstood !

Comment: @FelixD. that would make my query more cluttered - here is the link to code https://github.com/Quantron7t/WPF.CP17

Comment: If you don't want changes reflected back to your model then don't use two-way binding, just use one way binding.  Basically for display purposes only.

Comment: @StephenWilson but the twoway binding mode helps me disable the update button :\ if the data is null or whitespace

Comment: The disabled binding for the button will still work.  It just means that the value can't be null because of the user clearing the textbox.  I think you need to go and study WPF and MVVM a bit more as I don't think you're grasping the main basic concepts that make it such a good platform.

Comment: @StephenWilson disabled button is not getting triggered i can assure you that because there is a live debug point on that command ... and i think people are not getting my query!

Comment: @StephenWilson basic concepts like what ? in specific ? data binding ? markup extensions ? icommand ??

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you basically want an editor `CarDetailsView` where the user manipulates data, but until the save button was pressed, you don't want the current editor status to be reflected in the `CarListView`?

Comment: @grek40 exactly! finally someone gets it

Comment: You shouldnt be utilizing the TwoWay Binding of a property to enforce the enable or disable of a button. You should have that button have a bound command and a `CanExecuteCommand` and then the `CanExecuteCommand` will determine if the button is enabled or disabled.

Comment: You may also want to look at Wpf Validation strategies. As it seems you need to validate before a submit.

Comment: @GingerNinja i am not submitting anything, its the close window button that worrying me just like a browser saving a state of page when tab is closed directly

Answer (score 0):

You can't set an `int` property or a `Country` property to an empty `string`.

You can set them to `null` if you define the properties as nullable:

```
public class Car
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public int? Price { get; set; }
    public Country? Country { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you try to detach the view from the viewmodel (changed view but want to keep the viewmodel property unchanged) but that's just a wrong approach.

If you have a list of persisted data and you want to edit one item, without reflecting the edit in the list before saving, then you need a separate viewmodel with separate data.
Get initial values based on a list item, let the user edit the data and explicitely write the changed data back into the list item at saving.

Tools like AutoMapper can ease the creation of editor items to some extent, if you want to avoid manual copying of the data to/from the editor viewmodel.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice - I will try out your way.. and also take a look into the automapper

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the solution to what i was looking for; as said in my OP the problem was that whenever i changed a value of the property bound to textbox that data is reflected back (even if the data is blank white space) to source no matter what - you click update or cancel or any button on window that closes the form.

***SOLUTION :***

I set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` to **Explicit**.

By default `UpdateSourceTrigger` is set to **default** which means the value change in property is reflected back to source.

When `UpdateSourceTrigger` is set to Explicit which basically means that changes made to values of binding are not sent back to the source even if the Mode is TwoWay or OneWayToSource.

Check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger(v=vs.110).aspx) what MSDN says about Binding.UpdateSourceTrigger Property

Comment: Honestly your so called solution is not very convincing. At least if you try to develop the MVVM way you shouldn't prevent the transfer of incomplete / wrong data to the viewmodel. You're not getting model validation if the data stay in the view without transfer.

Comment: @grek40 you are right i do need to implement a validation; however, as long as i can govern the back flow of data manually - this solution is helping me out!